# Does AWS Step functions support binary data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create pipeline by using AWS Step functions for binary data processing.

Right now I've done [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) step-by-step guide from AWS blog about binary support for API Integrations with Amazon API Gateway and it seems works.

But when I change Resources > POST > Integration type > AWS Service on `AWS Service: Step Functions`, add action, execution role, add to Body Mapping Templates `stateMachineArn` and make new POST request I've got new execution in state machine where input was `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add action in Action field. All what you can to add is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_Operations.html
As example if you want create method for execution starting, type in Action 'StartExecution' and input will

```
{   "input": "string",   "name": "string",   "stateMachineArn": "string" }
```

here is one more example how create APIgateway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html